# How to add default language url path on Odoo website

Tags: url, path, odoo, multilingual, odoo-14

I develop my company website on Odoo 14 and it is multilingual. The default language is English. For other language it adds language path like:

```
for Italian: /it/
for German: /de/
```

But for English it does not add  any path because it is the default language. I would like to have the default language path too. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily by adding the language to the URL as shown below:

```
http://<website_domain_name>/it
```

or

```
http://<website_domain_name>/de
```

Comment: My point was to add language paths automatically. So, for Italian and German there is no problem. I just would like to find a way to add the default language path as well instead of without any language path.

for instance: 

default:
`domain.com/page`

italian:
`domain.com/it/page`

german:
`domain.com/de/page`